# My app is working fine in the simulator but then when i plug my phone in it breaks

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios9, xcode7-beta5

I've been working on an app in the simulator and it uses parse. However, when I connect my phone (which does have the proper certificates and I do have a developer account) it gives me this error: `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` What does that mean. I amm using `Xcode beta-7.5` and I have iOS 9 beta on my phone. I made a different app that does nothing, but when I upload that it works just fine.

Comment: There should be more relevant information above that error message. Please add it to your question.

Comment: its with parse it says there is some bitcode thingy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove test section, it will work

Comment: under what? where do i find test section

Comment: fixed it by disabling bitcode i don't even know what bitcode is.